# Change type of points of highchart's scatter chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using highcharts to display some kind of scatter chart.

I have multiple series, but I want all of their points to be dots, just like for the first point/line and last point/line (no triangles etc.), how can I do so?

```
export class EmpiricalChartComponent implements OnInit {

  Highcharts: typeof Highcharts = Highcharts;
  chartOptions: Highcharts.Options;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.chartOptions = {
      plotOptions: {
        scatter: {
          lineWidth: 2
        }
      },
      yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
          text: ''
        }
      },
      series: [
        {
          type: 'scatter',
          data: [...]
        }, {
          type: 'scatter',
          data: [...]
        }, {
          type: 'scatter',
          data: [...]
        },
      ]
    };

}
```

Current graph:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `marker` property inside each serie with `symbol: 'circle'` like this:

```
 this.chartOptions = {
      plotOptions: {
        scatter: {
          lineWidth: 2
        }
      },
      yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
          text: ''
        }
      },
      series: [
        {
          type: 'scatter',
          data: [...],
          marker: {
            symbol: 'circle'
          }
        }, {
          type: 'scatter',
          data: [...],
          marker: {
            symbol: 'circle'
          }
        }, {
          type: 'scatter',
          data: [...],
          marker: {
            symbol: 'circle'
          }
        },
      ]
    };
```